# generate and propagate signals for 64 bit kogge stone adder using loop in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am writing a verilog code for 64 bit kogge stone adder. Please help me how to write preprocessing stage of computing generate and propagate signals for 64 bit inputs using loop in verilog?

```
module preprocessing64bit(a,b,g,p);
input  [63:0] a,b;
output [63:0] g,p;
reg [63:0] g,p;
integer i;

always @ (a or b)
begin
for(i=0;i<64;i=i+1)
begin 
assign p[i]=a[i]^b[i];
assign g[i]=a[i]&b[i];
end
end

endmodule
```

This code I wrote but is not working. I researched a lot over internet but unable to find the correct way.
Error messages being shown on compilation in Modelsim

Error: C:/Users/Ankit/Documents/verilog project/preprocessing64bit.v(11): Bit-select of reg not allowed in procedural continuous assignment: p.

** Error: C:/Users/Ankit/Documents/verilog project/preprocessing64bit.v(12): Bit-select of reg not allowed in procedural continuous assignment: g

Answer (score 2):

If you have no experience with Verilog can can understand that the error message has you baffled. Yes, you have made an error, but it has nothing to do whatsoever with the bit-select.

You have used an 'assign' inside an 'always @(...)
'assign' is used with wires and out side 'always' sections.
The correct syntax would be:

```
   p[i]=a[i]^b[i];
   g[i]=a[i]&b[i];
```

That will solve your syntax error and the code is then correct.
But let's have another look at your code.....

You are using a for loop to work with bits. But Verilog logical operators will work on vectors. This is much simple and faster:

```
always @ (a or b)
begin
    p = a ^ b;
    g = a & b ;
end
```

The next improvement is that you can now also drop the 'always' section and use assigns. But beware an 'assign' work with a 'wire', not a 'reg' thus it becomes:

```
module preprocessing64bit(a,b,g,p);
input  [63:0] a,b;
output [63:0] g,p;

   assign p = a ^ b;
   assign g = a & b;

endmodule
```

As last improvement I would not use the old port definitions but use the new Verilog 2001 syntax:

```
module preprocessing64bit (
 input  [63:0] a,b,
 output [63:0] g,p
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have generated n bit Kogge Stone adder using verilog code
I am looking for job in RTL Design and Verification. 
Please contact me gmail- mohamedyashirh@gmail.com  

 module nbitksa#(parameter n=64)(
       input [n-1:0]a,b,
       input cin,
        output [n-1:0]g,      //sum 
        output [n:0]h,        //concartinated carry and sum
        output c              //carry
       );

  wire [n-1:0]m,w;             // n-1  half adder
  wire  [n-1:1]x,y;            // first stage  output
  wire  [n-1:2]u,v;            // second stage output
  wire   [n-1:4]j,k;           // third stage output
  wire   [n-1:8]p,q;           // fourth stage output
  wire   [n-1:16]z,l;          // fifth stage output
  wire   [n-1:32]s,t;          // sixth stage output
  wire   [n-1:0]su;            // sum output
 genvar i;
 generate
      for(i=0;i<=n-1;i=i+1)
         begin
              p p0(a[i],b[i],m[i],w[i]);                  //instantiate half adder module                         
             if(i==0)                       
                   assign su[i]=cin^m[i];   
             else                   
                   begin

                          // first stage  output

                        q q0(m[i-1],m[i],w[i],w[i-1],x[i],y[i]);        //instantiate carry propagation and generation module            
                           if(i==1)
                             begin
                               assign su[i]=m[i]^w[i-1];         
                             end  
                          // second stage output                            
                         if(i>1)                                      
                              begin
                                  if(i==2)
                                         begin
                                        q q1(m[i-2],x[i],y[i],n[i-2],u[i],v[i]);     //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                          assign su[i]=m[i]^y[i-1];
                                         end
                                  else
                                         begin
                                           q q2(x[i-2],x[i],y[i],y[i-2],u[i],v[i]);   //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                             if(i==3)
                                                assign su[i]=m[i]^v[i-1];
                                          end
                                  // third stage output
                                  if(i>3)
                                      begin
                                                 if(i==4)
                                                    begin
                                                      q q3(m[i-4],u[i],v[i],n[i-4],j[i],k[i]);     //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                                      assign su[i]=m[i]^v[i-1];
                                                    end
                                                  else if(i==5)
                                                     begin
                                                       q q4(x[i-4],u[i],v[i],y[i-4],j[i],k[i]);     //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                                       assign su[i]=m[i]^k[i-1];
                                                     end
                                                  else
                                                     begin
                                                       q q5(u[i-4],u[i],v[i],v[i-4],j[i],k[i]);      //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                                       assign su[i]=m[i]^k[i-1];
                                                     end
                                      // fourth stage output

                                         if(i>7)
                                             begin                                                        
                                                if(i==8)
                                                   begin     
                                                      q q6(m[i-8],j[i],k[i],n[i-8],p[i],q[i]);       //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                                      assign  su[i]=m[i]^k[i-1];
                                                   end
                                                else if(i==9)
                                                   begin     
                                                      q q7(x[i-8],j[i],k[i],y[i-8],p[i],q[i]);       //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                                      assign  su[i]=m[i]^q[i-1];
                                                   end
                                                else if((i==10) || (i==11))
                                                   begin     
                                                      q q8(u[i-8],j[i],k[i],v[i-8],p[i],q[i]);        //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                                      assign  su[i]=m[i]^q[i-1];
                                                   end
                                                else
                                                   begin     
                                                      q q9(j[i-8],j[i],k[i],k[i-8],p[i],q[i]);        //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                                      assign su[i]=m[i]^q[i-1];
                                                   end
                                            // fifth stage output
                                               if(i>15)
                                             begin                                                        
                                                if(i==16)
                                                   begin     
                                                      q q10(m[i-16],p[i],q[i],n[i-16],z[i],l[i]);      //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                                      assign  su[i]=m[i]^q[i-1];
                                                   end
                                                else if(i==17)
                                                   begin     
                                                      q q11(x[i-16],p[i],q[i],y[i-16],z[i],l[i]);      //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                                      assign  su[i]=m[i]^l[i-1];
                                                   end
                                                else if((i==18) || (i==19))
                                                   begin     
                                                      q q12(u[i-16],p[i],q[i],v[i-16],z[i],l[i]);       //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                                      assign  su[i]=m[i]^l[i-1];
                                                   end
                                                else if((i>=20) && (i<=23))
                                                   begin     
                                                      q q13(j[i-16],p[i],q[i],k[i-16],z[i],l[i]);       //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                                      assign  su[i]=m[i]^l[i-1];
                                                   end
                                                else
                                                   begin     
                                                      q q14(p[i-16],p[i],q[i],q[i-16],z[i],l[i]);       //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                                      assign su[i]=m[i]^l[i-1];
                                                   end
                                          // sixth stage output
                                           if(i>31)
                                             begin                                                        
                                                if(i==32)
                                                   begin     
                                                      q q10(m[i-32],z[i],l[i],n[i-32],s[i],t[i]);      //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                                      assign  su[i]=m[i]^l[i-1];
                                                   end
                                                else if(i==33)
                                                   begin     
                                                      q q11(x[i-32],z[i],l[i],y[i-32],s[i],t[i]);       //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                                      assign  su[i]=m[i]^t[i-1];
                                                   end
                                                else if((i==34) || (i==35))
                                                   begin     
                                                      q q12(u[i-32],z[i],l[i],v[i-32],s[i],t[i]);       //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                                      assign  su[i]=m[i]^t[i-1];
                                                   end
                                                else if((i>=36) && (i<=39))
                                                   begin     
                                                      q q13(j[i-32],z[i],l[i],k[i-32],s[i],t[i]);       //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                                      assign  su[i]=m[i]^t[i-1];
                                                   end
                                                 else if((i>=40) && (i<=47))
                                                   begin     
                                                      q q13(p[i-32],z[i],l[i],p[i-32],s[i],t[i]);       //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                                      assign  su[i]=m[i]^t[i-1];
                                                   end
                                                else
                                                   begin     
                                                      q q14(z[i-32],z[i],l[i],l[i-32],s[i],t[i]);        //instantiate carry propagation and generation module  
                                                      assign su[i]=m[i]^t[i-1];
                                                   end
                                             end
                                            end
                                         end
                                     end 
                                end                        
                    end                 
           end
  endgenerate 
assign g=su;
assign h={c,g};              // concartinated sum
assign c=(n>32)?t[n-1]:((n>16)?l[n-1]:((n>8)?q[n-1]:((n>4)?k[n-1]:v[n-1])));  //selecting the particular carry bit of n-stages
endmodule

module p(             //half adder module
      input a,b,
      output s,c
      );
  assign s=a^b;
  assign c=a&b;
endmodule
module q(             //carry propagation and generation module
      input a,b,g,f,
      output s,c
      );
  assign s=a&b;
  assign c=g|(b&f);
  endmodule
```